# Replacing the 404 Page Not Found error page

Tags: website-features, personal-website

I am new to managing websites and just set up a personal website for myself.

I had like to replace `404 Not Found Error` page, in the same way many websites do it.

How do I go about it?

Comment: Are you using Apache, IIS, or ..?

Comment: Danlefree is right, it depends on what web server you are using.  On IIS its under the custom error pages section of IIS management console.  If you are on linux then you are likely apache. If you are hosting on windows then its either Apache or IIS but likely IIS.

Comment: Apache. And sorry for not mentioning this earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For apache:

Create a file with the name ***.htaccess*** put it in the root of your website and inside that file write:

***ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html***

Instead of ***/notfound.html*** write the path to your 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

you can found here how to do what you want with Apache HTTPD:

[Custom Error Responses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/custom-error.html)